# Internet Explorer z index not working with Iframe

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
<div class="zoomerimage">
    <iframe id="oriimage" style="overflow:hidden;" title="test.pdf" src="test.pdf"   height="800" width="100%" ></iframe>
    <div class="noteoverlay">
        Notes
    </div>
</div>

.zoomerimage {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.noteoverlay{
    background: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

I have a div structure like above now I want noteoverlay class to be overlay on iframe.
Above css holds good for all browsers except IE.
In IE the noteoverlay div is coming behind iframe.

Is there any specific styles for IE ?

Comment: for #oriimage ?
I have tried but din't made any trick